# Trying to build two C++20 modules together into one module using clang++ v12

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, c++20

I'm trying to link two C++20 modules together using clang++ v12. Linking C++20 Modules to an executable works fine for example, below *main* is an executable:

clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules -pedantic -Wall -fprebuilt-module-path=. main.cpp mainUi.pcm video.pcm audio.pcm CameraWidgetFactory.pcm AudioInterfaces.pcm -o main

compile with no errors, but linking to another Module gives this error.  Here's the error and  command from the Makefile:

clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules -pedantic -Wall -fmodules-ts -c -fprebuilt-module-path=. AudioFactory.cpp AudioFactory.hpp AudioInput.pcm -Xclang -emit-module-interface

and the error:

clang-12: /home/james/llvm-project/clang/lib/Frontend/FrontendAction.cpp:636: bool clang::FrontendAction::BeginSourceFile(clang::CompilerInstance&, const clang::FrontendInputFile&): Assertion `hasASTFileSupport() && "This action does not have AST file support!"' failed.

PLEASE submit a bug report to https://bugs.llvm.org/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.

0. Program arguments: /usr/local/bin/clang-12 -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -main-file-name AudioInput.pcm -mrelocation-model static -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -fno-split-dwarf-inlining -debugger-tuning=gdb -resource-dir /usr/local/lib/clang/12.0.0 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++20 -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/james/eclipse-workspace/AudioFactory -ferror-limit 19 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fmodules -fmodules-ts -fimplicit-module-maps -fmodules-cache-path=/home/james/.cache/clang/ModuleCache -fprebuilt-module-path=. -fmodules-validate-system-headers -fcolor-diagnostics -emit-module-interface -faddrsig -o AudioInput.o -x pcm AudioInput.pcm
   #0 0x000055822646a3d1 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&, int) (/usr/local/bin/clang-12+0x33793d1)
   #1 0x0000558226467f74 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() (/usr/local/bin/clang-12+0x3376f74)
   #2 0x00005582264680e0 SignalHandler(int) (/usr/local/bin/clang-12+0x33770e0)
   #3 0x00007fe8847cd3c0 __restore_rt (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+0x153c0)
   #4 0x00007fe88426d18b raise /build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51:1
   #5 0x00007fe88424c859 abort /build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/stdlib/abort.c:81:7
   #6 0x00007fe88424c729 get_sysdep_segment_value /build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/intl/loadmsgcat.c:509:8
   #7 0x00007fe88424c729 _nl_load_domain /build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/intl/loadmsgcat.c:970:34
   #8 0x00007fe88425df36 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x36f36)
   #9 0x0000558226dc0128 clang::FrontendAction::BeginSourceFile(clang::CompilerInstance&, clang::FrontendInputFile const&) (/usr/local/bin/clang-12+0x3ccf128)
   #10 0x0000558226d6cd72 clang::CompilerInstance::ExecuteAction(clang::FrontendAction&) (/usr/local/bin/clang-12+0x3c7bd72)
   #11 0x0000558226e94598 clang::ExecuteCompilerInvocation(clang::CompilerInstance*) (/usr/local/bin/clang-12+0x3da3598)
   #12 0x00005582240370ed cc1_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) (/usr/local/bin/clang-12+0xf460ed)
   #13 0x0000558224032318 ExecuteCC1Tool(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<char const*>&) (/usr/local/bin/clang-12+0xf41318)
   #14 0x0000558223f7fd9c main (/usr/local/bin/clang-12+0xe8ed9c)
   #15 0x00007fe88424e0b3 __libc_start_main /build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:342:3
   #16 0x0000558224031e6e _start (/usr/local/bin/clang-12+0xf40e6e)
   clang-12: error: unable to execute command: Aborted (core dumped)
   clang-12: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
   clang version 12.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git a5f95887d0f8d27f1c33f19944d0c1da66aef606)
   Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
   Thread model: posix
   InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin
   clang-12: note: diagnostic msg:

---

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang-12: note: diagnostic msg: /tmp/AudioFactory-462949.cpp
clang-12: note: diagnostic msg: /tmp/AudioFactory-462949.cache
clang-12: note: diagnostic msg: /tmp/AudioFactory-9851b0.hh
clang-12: note: diagnostic msg: /tmp/AudioFactory-9851b0.cache
clang-12: note: diagnostic msg: /tmp/AudioFactory-462949.sh
clang-12: note: diagnostic msg:

---

make: *** [Makefile:19: AudioFactory.pcm] Error 254

Can anyone tell what's wrong here?

Comment: The error speaks for itself, looks like a compiler bug.

Comment: Any reason to not take them at their word and submit the compiler bug report? `clang` seems to think it's a problem on their end; I can't imagine they'd encourage you to submit a bug report when it might just be bad code.

Comment: It just happened today thought someone else might know something. Will do the bug report if one doesn't already exist.